# Java Swing GUI Not Opening

Tags: java, swing

My swing program with radio buttons isn't opening and I have been looking everywhere and nothing helped. I tried doing the same thing with my previous program and that somehow worked.

Note: I used Eclipse Neon.1 and "Build Automatically" was checked and I even attempted to clean the program and restarted Eclipse and nothing helped.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainClass extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new MainClass();
    }

    private JButton buttonOK;
    private JLabel label;

    MainClass() {
        this.setSize(350, 150);
        this.setTitle("Pizza Order");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JRadioButton small, medium, large, thin, thick;

        label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("Choose your size:");
        panel.add(label);

        ButtonGroup size = new ButtonGroup();
        ButtonGroup crust = new ButtonGroup();

        small = new JRadioButton("Small");
        medium = new JRadioButton("Medium");
        large = new JRadioButton("Large");
        size.add(small);
        size.add(medium);
        size.add(large);
        panel.add(small);
        panel.add(medium);
        panel.add(large);

        thin = new JRadioButton("Thin Crust");
        thick = new JRadioButton("Thick Crust");
        crust.add(thin);
        crust.add(thick);
        panel.add(thin);
        panel.add(thick);

        buttonOK = new JButton("OK");
        buttonOK.addActionListener(e -> buttonOKClick());
        panel.add(buttonOK);
    }

    public void buttonOKClick() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainClass.this, "Your pizza is being delivered!", "Pizza Delivery",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part of your code should be responsible for showing your GUI? Where are you *setting its visibility*?

Comment: @Pshemo Welp. I forgot to set the visibility. Thanks for reminding me. And the part which is responsible for showing the GUI is in the MainClass() constructor.

Comment: You also forgot to add/setContentPane `panel` to your frame.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Sorry I am new to Swing.

Comment: You created instance of panel, set it up, but forgot to add it to frame (your MainClass instance) which should show it. Remember that in your code you can create many panels, but you need to decide which one of them to print. I suggest taking your time and spending it on entire swing tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html or for now part about panels https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html.

Comment: @Pshemo Okay. Thanks for the links.